# Why `text_size_body` has different size in AppCompat library and Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

**v21\values.xml**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Material.Body1">
        <item name="textSize">@dimen/text_size_body_1_material</item>
</style>
```

Text size

```
<dimen name="text_size_body_1_material">14sp</dimen>
```

**values\values.xml**

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material</item>
</style>
```

Text size

```
<dimen name="abc_text_size_body_1_material">16sp</dimen>
```

**Question:** what is the reason why google define different sizes for `text_size_body` in AppCompat library and Android Lollipop.

**P.S.** other sizes seems to be the same.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, but I can't see it reported. Maybe @chris-banes knows something about it.

Comment: @Edi The issue is reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80749. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, Android starts by looking at the default folder **values** for all of the values you defined through xml resources (in your case **values/dimens.xml**). But in your case you have defined an "overloading" resource folder, **v21**, which overwrites default values if your app is running on a device with Android v21+. That's why the text looks different on different Android versions (v21+ vs v20-).

See [Android documentation about resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: I have updated question to be more specific. That's not what I am asking.

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk I see. I dont't know the answer, just a guess: maybe to better follow style guidelines for Lollipop and pre-Lollipop, which are different?

Answer (score 0):

I think the *abc_* prefixed values are for ActionBarCompat. So it's the body text size for the ActionBar.

Comment: No, all dimensions in AppCompat library have prefix `abc_`

Comment: Yes and AppCompat only styles the ActionBar, as befor Material Design it was used to bring the ActionBar on pre-HC devices